# How to convert the columns into rows in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have a csv file with the following data as follows:
[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXl0J.png)

i want to convert the columns into rows:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95qbb.png)

I have tried the following code:

```
mydict = dict(zip(df.title, df.score))
    # s = pd.Series(list(mydict.items()))
    # df_final = pd.DataFrame(s)
```

and write the ouput to a new csv file. How can i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: hope solution worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'title':['p1','p2','p3'],
                   'score':[1,0.1,2]})
print (df)
  title  score
0    p1    1.0
1    p2    0.1
2    p3    2.0

df1 = pd.DataFrame([df.score.values], columns=df.title.values)
```

Alternative:

```
df1 = df.set_index('title')['score'].to_frame(0).T.rename_axis(None, 1)
```

---

```
print (df1)
    p1   p2   p3
0  1.0  0.1  2.0

df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very small solution

```
import pandas as pd
df =  pd.read_csv("inputfile")
print df.set_index('title').T
```

Original df:

```
  cluster       budget
0       a  4133.333333
1       b   300.000000
2       c   575.000000
```

Output of above code:

```
cluster            a      b      c
budget   4133.333333  300.0  575.0
```